# Hot restart/reload broken after flutter upgrade and flutter downgrade on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Yesterday I did run flutter upgrade but then the `intl` package was giving some version incompatibility issues so after a few tries I just run flutter downgrade to go back to previous version.
Now my app goes crazy when I hot restart it.. it works normally if I uninstall it an
reinstall it again, bau as soon as I press hot restart or hot reload it goes crazy like in a loop trying to rebuild the view, so I have to uninstall it again..

Have you experienced this situation?
What can I try before reinstalling Android Studio?

This is my flutter doctor.
Thank you very much.
Cheers.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.23.0-19.0.pre.20, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
   • Flutter version 1.23.0-19.0.pre.20 at /Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter
   • Framework revision 66cf8d47a3 (10 weeks ago), 2020-10-14 14:47:28 +0900
   • Engine revision adf5b59485
   • Dart version 2.11.0 (build 2.11.0-217.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
   • Android SDK at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/Android/sdk
   • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.2
   • ANDROID_HOME = /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/Android/sdk
   • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/Android/sdk
   • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
   • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
   • Xcode at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
   • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
   • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
   • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
   • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
   • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
   • Dart plugin version 193.7361
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
   • iPad (7th generation) (mobile) • CF798CBE-3FBF-47E3-A7DF-8E762B4B8CEC • ios            •
     com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5 (simulator)
   • Web Server (web)               • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
   • Chrome (web)                   • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
     87.0.4280.88

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to your problem. When I switched to the stable channel on the beta channel, the problem was resolved. You should try it too ...
You can switch to the stable channel by doing the following steps.

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: I tried but the result is the same. I even deleted the SDK and reinstalled from scratch, but nothing changed. Any suggestions on what to try ? Many thanks

Comment: Can you create a new flutter project from the terminal and open that project ?

Comment: Yeap, it works properly. new project hot restarts normally.. what can have broken in my other projects?

Comment: When you change the Flutter channel, the systematic of the codes you wrote in that channel version also changes. To fix this problem, you should follow the steps below ...


You have to delete the folder containing the dart tools in your other projects.

`.dart_tool`

Comment: The .dart_tool folder gets deleted every time you run  flutter clean, so the problem must be somewhere else. I tried deleting the pubspec.lock file to see if it was a problem with some package but nope..it keeps goin mad if I relaunch the app without deleting it from the simulator first

Comment: No, you do what I say, the system will rebuild itself and your applications will open properly this time. It was the same with me, so I was saved.

Comment: I tried deleting manually the `.dart_tool` folder from the project and running it again. Same behavior as before.

Comment: The problem with mine was resolved after I did what I said. All that's left to do is copy the dart files from all projects to a separate location. Create a standard project one by one with flutter create and add your other projects to those folders ... there is no other solution ...